# Fortran77 program does not execute

Tags: fortran

**Working Fortran compilers sometimes generate invalid Win32 .exe files**

Hello everybody,

several working Fortran compilers seem to have a strange behavior in certain situations. I have tried to compile and run Prof. John Denton's programs which can be found here:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8i0jyxzjb57q4j4/AABD9GQ1MUFwUm5hMWFylucva?dl=0

The different versions of the programs Meangen und Stagen could be compiled and worked fine. The last program named Multall also has several different versions. As before, the appropriate source codes could be compiled without any problems. But: as I tried to run the resulting .exe files, I got a very strange error message saying Multall's .exe would NOT be a valid Win32 executable.

I used four different Fortran compilers (g77, Cygwin, Mingw, FTN95) on Windows XP and Windows 8, always with the same result. I made several tests, and it seems to me the reason of the strange error message is the huge amount of source code Multall consists of. There are much more than 16000 lines of code, so maybe the memory being allocated by default by the compiler for the code segment is too small and an overflow occurs.

I tried several command line options of the g77 compiler in order to increase the code segment's amount of memory, but none worked. Can anybody tell me which of the g77's command line options make the huge program Multall's .exe work? Or maybe I am wrong, and the strange error message has nothing to do with the code segment? Who can help me?

Thanks a lot, I highly appreciate your help

Comment: 160,000 isn't a very big program - there are plenty of examples with 1,000,000+  lines and these compile fine. To go further can you show us exactly what you did, along with the exact error messages generated and the compiler versions used? Even better would be to see if you can generate a small code which shows exactly the same symptoms. That said my guess after a 5 minute look is that the AT LEAST 3.8 GByte in the common blocks (which should have been ditched 25 years ago) is what is causing your problem.

Comment: As Ian hinted, you must use allocatable arrays (and x64 mode) in ordet to exceed the 3.8 GB limit.

Comment: Code size was 16,000. Not 160,000. But your comment is not affected by this.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the problem is not the program size but the stack size. This is due to the large common blocks. As a test you could reduce JD in commall-open-18.3 to 1000 and you will notice that the problem is solved.
You could check whether the arrays are not oversized and adjust some parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much, I hope this will solve the issue !

Comment: Reducing JD to 1000 does solve the problem on Linux at least. I'd say rewrite the code without common blocks and maybe in modern fortran...

Comment: Thanks I set JD in commall-open-18.3 to 1000 (previous 2500) and 'Not a valid Win32 program'  is gone, the program ran OK.

Comment: Common blocks normally go to the static section, not to the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reducing common blocks - without any effect - then I tried on another computer and there the compilation went fine and the code runs - I am guessing it is some sort of screw-up of the libraries - maybe because I made a messy (first) installation where I didn't really know what I wass doing - but I really don't know.

Comment: Sharing update is helpful to others, but please do not post updates as answers unless you have a solution or some sort of conclusion to the problem.